# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams in android?

Tags: android

I am facing crash at my app. Class cast exception occur only 420 X 800 device resoluition (KitKat 19 API). same code run in other resolution of device.why i am getting crash only 420 x 800 device resolution.

Here is my code

i am open grid view in expandable listview and set hight of grid view dynamically.

```
     public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
        {

            private Context _context;
            private ArrayList<Object> _listDataHeader = new ArrayList<Object>(); // header titles
            // child data in format of header title, child title
            private HashMap<Object, ArrayList<Object>> _listDataChild = new HashMap<Object, ArrayList<Object>>();
            public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Object> listDataHeader,
                                         HashMap<Object, ArrayList<Object>> listChildData) {
                this._context = context;
                this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
                this._listDataChild = listChildData;

            }

            @Override
            public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon)
            {
                return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                        .get(childPosititon);
            }

            @Override
            public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
            {
                return childPosition;
            }
            public class ViewHolder
            {

                public TextView _groupTxt = null;
                public GridView _subCatGrid;
                public GridAdapter _gridAdapter;
                public RelativeLayout _subCatll;
                public ImageView _catIcon;
                public TextView _catCount;

            }

            @Override
            public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                                     boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                if(_listDataHeader.size()>0)
                {
                    try {
                        CategoryBean catBean = (CategoryBean) _listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);

                        ArrayList<SubCatBean> beanArrayList = catBean.getChildArrayList();


                        ViewHolder _viewHolder;

                        if (convertView == null) {
                            _viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.cat_child_row, null);
                            _viewHolder._subCatGrid = (GridView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sub_cat_grid);
                            _viewHolder._subCatll = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subCatLL);


                            convertView.setTag(_viewHolder);
                        } else {
                            _viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                        }

                        System.out.println("group position" + groupPosition);
                        _viewHolder._gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(getActivity(), beanArrayList);
                        _viewHolder._subCatGrid.setAdapter(_viewHolder._gridAdapter);
                        _viewHolder._gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        //dynamic set hight and width from runtime
                        _viewHolder._subCatll.measure(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                        int height = _viewHolder._subCatll.getMeasuredHeight();
                        _viewHolder._subCatll.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height));    
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }

                return convertView;
            }

            @Override
            public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
if(this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size()==0)
                {

                    Toast.makeText(this._context, "No Data Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return 0;
                }
                else {
                    return 1;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
                return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
            }

            @Override
            public int getGroupCount() {
                return this._listDataHeader.size();
            }

            @Override
            public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
                return groupPosition;
            }

            @Override
            public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                                     View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                if(_listDataHeader.size()>0)
                {
                    try {
                        CategoryBean bean = (CategoryBean) _listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
                        ViewHolder _viewHolder;
                        if (convertView == null)
                        {
                            _viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.catlist_row, null);

                            _viewHolder._groupTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.catTxt);
                            _viewHolder._catIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cat_icon);
                            _viewHolder._catCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.catcount);
                            convertView.setTag(_viewHolder);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                        }
                        _viewHolder._groupTxt.setText(bean.getCatName());
                        _viewHolder._catCount.setText(String.valueOf(bean.getChildArrayList().size()));

                        if(isExpanded)
                        {
                            if (groupPosition == 0)
                            {
                                _viewHolder._catIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.food_and_drinkblue);
                            }
                            if (groupPosition == 1)
                            {
                                _viewHolder._catIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.computersblue);
                            }
                            if (groupPosition == 2)
                            {
                                _viewHolder._catIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.computersblue);
                            }
                            if (groupPosition == 3)
                            {
                                _viewHolder._catIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tools_and_homeblue);
                            }
                            if (groupPosition == 4)
                            {
                                _viewHolder._catIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.babiesblue);
                            }
                            if (groupPosition == 5)
                            {
                                _viewHolder._catIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.autoblue);
                            }
                            if (groupPosition == 6)
                            {
                                _viewHolder._catIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.clothingsblue);
                            }
                            if (groupPosition == 7)
                            {
                                _viewHolder._catIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hairblue);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (groupPosition == 0)
                            {
                                _viewHolder._catIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.food_and_drinkgrey);
                            }

                            if (groupPosition == 1)
                            {
                                _viewHolder._catIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.computersgrey);
                            }
                            if (groupPosition == 2)
                            {
                                _viewHolder._catIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.computersgrey);
                            }
                            if (groupPosition == 3)
                            {
                                _viewHolder._catIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tools_and_homegrey);
                            }
                            if (groupPosition == 4)
                            {
                                _viewHolder._catIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.babiesgrey);
                            }
                            if (groupPosition == 5)
                            {
                                _viewHolder._catIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.autogrey);
                            }
                            if (groupPosition == 6)
                            {
                                _viewHolder._catIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.clothingsgrey);
                            }
                            if (groupPosition == 7)
                            {
                                _viewHolder._catIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hairgrey);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {

                    }
                }
                return convertView;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasStableIds() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                return true;
            }
        }

         public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter
            {
                Activity activity;
                private Typeface font;
                public ArrayList<SubCatBean> data = new ArrayList<>();

                public GridAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<SubCatBean> data)
                {
                    this.activity = activity;
                    this.data = data;
                }

                public int getCount() {
                    return data.size();
                }

                @Override
                public Object getItem(int i) {
                    return data.get(i);
                }

                @Override
                public long getItemId(int i) {
                    return i;
                }

                public class ViewHolder
                {
                    public TextView _childBtn = null;
                }

                @Override
                public View getView(final int i,View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup)
                {        // LayoutInflator to call external grid_item.xml file
                    final SubCatBean bean = (SubCatBean)data.get(i);
                    try {
                        ViewHolder  view_holder;
                        if (convertView == null)
                        {
                            view_holder = new ViewHolder();
                            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_cat_row, null);
                            // set value into text view
                            view_holder._childBtn = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childTxt);

                            convertView.setTag(view_holder);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            view_holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                        }
                        //------------------------//----------------------------------//
                        if (data.get(i).getSubCatStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
                        {
                            view_holder._childBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey);
                            view_holder._childBtn.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
                            bean.setSubCatValue(0);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            view_holder._childBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);
                            view_holder._childBtn.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
                            bean.setSubCatValue(1);
                        }
                        view_holder._childBtn.setText(bean.getSubCatName());

                        view_holder._childBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v)
                            {
                                System.out.println("child position" + i);
                                if(SharedPref.getSharedPrefData(getActivity(),SharedPref.PREFRENCE_KEY_LOGIN).length()==0)
                                {
                                    if (data.get(i).getSubCatValue() == 0)
                                    {
                                        bean.setSubCatValue(1);
                                        bean.setSubCatStatus("1");
                                        addData.add(bean.getSubCatID());
                                        System.out.println("add value" + bean.getSubCatID());
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        bean.setSubCatValue(0);
                                        bean.setSubCatStatus("0");
                                        for (int j = 0; j < addData.size(); j++)
                                        {
                                            if (addData.get(j).equals(bean.getSubCatID()))
                                            {
                                                addData.remove(j);
                                                System.out.println("add value remove"+bean.getSubCatID());
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (data.get(i).getSubCatValue() == 0)
                                    {
                                        bean.setSubCatValue(1);
                                        bean.setSubCatStatus("1");
                                        main_valueAfter = String.valueOf(bean.getSubCatID());
                                        true_valueAfter = "1";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        bean.setSubCatValue(0);
                                        bean.setSubCatStatus("0");
                                        main_valueAfter = String.valueOf(bean.getSubCatID());
                                        true_valueAfter = "0";
                                    }
                                    callSetCategory();
                                }

                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });

                    }catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return convertView;
                }

            }
```

I have debug also but logcat not provide perticular line which having null but its crash after debug point cross "return convertview" line in second time.

here is my logcat

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
            at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1826)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1793)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1349)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1608)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2087)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2013)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1770)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1019)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5725)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
```

cat_child_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/subCatLL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/sub_cat_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

sub_cat_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/childTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:background="@drawable/grey"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it's not `NPE`. you are setting wrong `layout params`. have you set layout param dynamically.?

Comment: @kishorejethava yes .. i have edit my code.

Comment: please change the `if (groupPosition == x)` series into `switch` statement

Comment: Show your `cat_child_row.xml` file.

Comment: post your xml layouts it could help us to identify the cause of the exception + a class cast exception is thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance. so xml might help us to make a better understanding of the problem

Comment: @DegenSharew :- where i am using if (groupPosition == x)  in this code?

Comment: @PiyushGupta :- i have edited my code.

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie :- Please look at this. i have edited my code

Comment: you have many `if (groupPosition ==` I thought you will get what I mean